# Regular Expression: allow only some specific set of words in the json string

Tags: regex

I have an case where in I have to allow only some specific set of words in the json string, example:

1. `{"name":"prashant","id":123,"address":"e-56 first floor"} This is valid\n`
2. `{"name":"prashant","address":"e-56 first floor"} This is valid\n`
3. `{"id":123,"address":"e-56 first floor"} This is valid\n`
4. `{"address":"e-56 first floor"} This is valid\n`

Any permutation combination for given words `(name|id|address)` is ok
Now Invalid

1. `{"name":"prashant","id":123,"address":"e-56 first floor" ,"phno":"9999999999"}`
   Not valid

if any word which is not the part of the given list has been used , then the whole string will be invalid , even though its contains 3 valid one invalid , will not allowed.

Can any one provide me the REGEX for this?

Comment: Do you have to use a regex? If you're working with JSON you'd be much better off parsing it as JSON.

Comment: Never, ever, ever, parse structured data with regular expressions, unless really really, REALLY required for a defendable edge case. Normally, for JSON use a JSON parser, an XML parser for XML, and a DOM parser for HTML.

Comment: We're not here to write your code for you. We can answer your questions about regexes, but actually writing your regexes is your job.

Comment: This post appears to be off-topic because it is a request for code, not a question.

Answer (score 0):

I would sugest to parse the data as JSON, there are many libraries for many languages. After you parsed the JSON you just need to check if all required fields are set.

Comment: Whilst a valid comment, this does not answer the actual question and is therefore better fit to be a comment on the question.

Comment: i wante to use it as @Pattern anotation in sprint model that why i needed

Comment: You should really not use a pattern for that, regex is to lowlevel for that task. It's like using regular expressions on HTML don't do it.

Comment: Actually i am using Postgres json object , i wanted to insure people only insert pre defined json , not any thing, as i cant in force this in Postgres db , thats why i was looking for work around.

Comment: Put that insert in a transaction if it fails roll it back and throw an exception in your code.

Answer (score 0):

This should be enough to validate if every key in the dictionary is valid. It will not detect some malformed json.

```
{("(name|id|address)":[^,]*,?)+}
```

The following one does not allow malformed json

```
{(("(name|address)":"[^"]*",)|("id":\d+,))*(("(name|address)":"[^"]*")|("id":\d+))}
```